# .net core - Jwt middleware authentication signing key being ignored

Tags: c#, .net, jwt, openid-connect, openiddict

I am using openiddict which is configured to to use json web tokens:

```
// Add authentication
services.AddAuthentication();

// Add OpenId Connect/OAuth2
services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddEntityFrameworkCoreStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddMvcBinders()
    .EnableTokenEndpoint("/connect/token")
    .AllowPasswordFlow()
    .AllowRefreshTokenFlow()
    .UseJsonWebTokens()      // access_token should be jwt
    // You can disable the HTTPS requirement during development or if behind a reverse proxy
    .DisableHttpsRequirement()
    // Register a new ephemeral key, that is discarded when the application
    // shuts down. Tokens signed using this key are automatically invalidated.
    // To be used during development
    .AddEphemeralSigningKey();
```

I have configured by JWT middleware in following manner:

```
// Add Jwt middleware for authentication
var secretKey = Configuration.Get<AppOptions>().Jwt.SecretKey;
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    RequireHttpsMetadata = env.IsProduction(),
    Audience = Configuration.Get<AppOptions>().Jwt.Audience,
    Authority = Configuration.Get<AppOptions>().Jwt.Authority,
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey)),

        ValidateIssuer = true,
        // makes no difference seemingly being ignored
        //ValidIssuer = Configuration.Get<AppOptions>().Jwt.Authority,

        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = Configuration.Get<AppOptions>().Jwt.Audience,

        ValidateLifetime = true,
    }
});

// Add OpedId Connect middleware
app.UseOpenIddict();
```

As you can see the issuer signing key is set to a symmetric key:

```
IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey)),
```

but the jwt access_tokens created have `alg` claim set to `RS256`, so it seems this setting is ignored and openiddict uses the RSA private key to sign the token generated from

```
.AddEphemeralSigningKey();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to force the openiddict to use symmetric key it has to be configured in openiddict

```
 services.AddOpenIddict()
.AddEntityFrameworkCoreStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
.AddMvcBinders()
.EnableTokenEndpoint("/connect/token")
.AllowPasswordFlow()
.AllowRefreshTokenFlow()
.UseJsonWebTokens()
// You can disable the HTTPS requirement during development or if behind a reverse proxy
.DisableHttpsRequirement()

// set your symmetric key

.AddSigningKey(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration.Get<AppOptions>().Jwt.SecretKey)));
```

Comment: Actually no, you need to register the signing key in both the OpenIddict options and the JWT bearer middleware options.

Comment: @Pinpoint It's working fine for me, by just setting it in the OpenIdDictservice

Comment: I really doubt it. If you don't register your symmetric signing key in the JWT middleware options, IdentityModel (the JWT library behind the JWT middleware) will throw an `SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException` (`IDX10500: Signature validation failed. No security keys were provided to validate the signature`) and your users will never be authenticated.

Answer (score 2):

In .net 2.0, you should also register your key in JWT middleware as shown:

```
  services.AddAuthentication(opt => {
                opt.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.SaveToken = true;
                //options.Audience = "http://localhost:13818/";
                //options.Authority = "http://localhost:13818/";                
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new 
                TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("iNivDmHLpUA223sqsfhqGbMRdRj1PVkH")),
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true
                };
            });
```